# JUnit Eclipse Oxygen - Display stack trace on test failure?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, usability

Is there a way to have eclipse show junit assertion errors (or more generally unhandled exceptions during testing for that matter) automatically without me going to the junit window, selecting the failed test, clicking the corresponding line on the right side, and then clicking the corresponding button each single time? This is ludicrous. There surely must be a better way I have not found yet!

Comment: The problem is: there are many perspectives. Question is: how would you expect that to happen. You select ... a class, package ... for "run as JUnit" ... and then .. which window should present you what?

Comment: the main problem is that test exceptions get suppressed in the console window. a good way to solve this, is to automatically open the last junit test exception in the exception console window. Or simply not suppress the exceptions in the console.